# How can I access this nested array without an Uncaught Type Error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, typeerror

So, I would just like to access the array properties that is displayed in image one below:

[image: Uncaught Type Error 1]

but when I attempt to do that with gameArray[0] on line 135, I get undefined as shown below:

[image: Uncaught Type Error 2]

Is there any way to access the information in this array and through gameArray with just an index?

```
//import Cursor from '/src/cursor.js';

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";
const MAZES = `${BASE_URL}/mazes`;
const PROFILE = `${BASE_URL}/users/`;
const SESSION = `${BASE_URL}/session`;
const LOGOUT = `${BASE_URL}/logout`;
const canvas = document.getElementById("mazeScreen");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const main = document.querySelector("main");
let gameArray = [];
//document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => loadMaze(4));
//document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => draw());
//console.log(loggedIn());

document.getElementById("logInButton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  console.log("click");
  let username = document.getElementById("logInField").value;
  console.log(username);
  document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML = makeUser(username);
  //renderUser(userInfo);

});

document.getElementById("getUser").addEventListener("click", getUser);

function getUser() {
  fetch(PROFILE)
  .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      json.forEach((user) => console.log(user));
    })
}

const makeUser = (username) => {
  fetch(`${PROFILE}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username
    })
  }).then(res => {
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log('ERROR'))
};

const loadMazes = () => {
  fetch(MAZES)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setMazeData(json, gameArray);
    });

    return gameArray;
};

const renderUser = (userHash) => {
  console.log("we are here");
  let div = document.getElementById("userInfo");
  let p = document.createElement("p");

  div.setAttribute("class", "card");
  console.log(userHash)
  //p.innerHTML = `Welcome ${userHash.username}`;

  div.appendChild(p);
  div.appendChild(button);
  div.appendChild(ul);
  
  document.getElementById("log_in_button").innerHTML = "Log out"
  setLogOut();
};

function loggedIn() {
  fetch(SESSION)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json)
  });
}

const setLogOut = () => {
  document.getElementById("scores").setAttribute("hidden", true);
  document.getElementById("log_in_button").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log("click");
    fetch(`${LOGOUT}`);
    document.getElementById("scores").setAttribute("hidden", true);
  });
}

// const renderScores = (scoreHash) => {

// }


let CANVAS_WIDTH = 1000;
let CANVAS_HEIGHT = 800;

let MAZE_WIDTH = 800;
let MAZE_HEIGHT = 600;

let PATH_SIZE = 10;
let COIN_RADIUS = 8;
let STARTING_AREA_WIDTH = 50;
let STARTING_AREA_HEIGHT = 50;
let FINISH_AREA_SIZE = 50;

let MAZE_X_CONSTANT = (CANVAS_WIDTH - MAZE_WIDTH) / 2;
let MAZE_Y_CONSTANT = (CANVAS_HEIGHT - MAZE_HEIGHT) / 2;

let pathString = "60 60 70 70 80 80 90 90 300 40 50 50 60 60 70 70 80 80 90 90 100 100";
let coinString = "200 200 220 220 230 230 300 300 400 400 500 500";

let pathString2 = "100 100 110 90 120 80 130 70 300 40 50 50 60 60 70 70 80 80 90 90 100 100";

function setMazeData(json, gameArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i ++) {
    var new_array = [parseInt(json[i].width), parseInt(json[i].height), MAZE_X_CONSTANT, MAZE_Y_CONSTANT,
    json[i].paths, json[i].coins, COIN_RADIUS, 
    FINISH_AREA_SIZE, PATH_SIZE, parseInt(JSON.stringify(json[i].id)), STARTING_AREA_WIDTH, STARTING_AREA_HEIGHT, json.length]
    gameArray.push(new_array);
  }
  return gameArray;
}

gameArray = loadMazes();

function createGame(gameId, gameArray) {
  console.log(gameId)
  console.log(gameArray[0]);
  let new_game = new Game(gameArray[gameId][0], gameArray[gameId][1], gameArray[gameId][2], gameArray[gameId][3], 
    gameArray[gameId][4], gameArray[gameId][5], gameArray[gameId][6], gameArray[gameId][7], gameArray[gameId][8], 
    gameArray[gameId][9], gameArray[gameId][10], gameArray[gameId][11], gameArray[gameId][12], gameArray)
  
  return new_game
}

let game = createGame(0, gameArray);
let lastTime = 0;

function gameLoop(timestamp) {
  let deltaTime = timestamp - lastTime;
  lastTime = timestamp;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
  drawMazeBorder(ctx);
  drawStartingArea(ctx);
  game.update(deltaTime);
  game.draw(ctx);
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

function drawMazeBorder(ctx) {
  ctx.strokeStyle="white"
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeRect(MAZE_X_CONSTANT - 2, MAZE_Y_CONSTANT - 2, MAZE_WIDTH + 2, MAZE_HEIGHT + 2);
}

function drawStartingArea(ctx) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "gray"
  ctx.fillRect(MAZE_X_CONSTANT, MAZE_Y_CONSTANT, STARTING_AREA_WIDTH, STARTING_AREA_HEIGHT);
}
```

Edited to add all the code in index.js.  You can see loadMazes which calls setMazeData.  Hopefully this works. Thanks.

Comment: post your code instead of images for we could help

Comment: __gameArray__ is being initialized by **loadMazes()** which you are not showing.

Comment: The last element from your new_game-array is the hole `gameArray`. Is this expected or should it be `gameArray[gameId][13]`?

Comment: Alright, just updated the post to show all the methods.

Comment: @Sascha the new game should have the array, as it's the object.  That way it can create other games.